# Rok and Mog, robotic creatures who lived on a dark, metallic planet, in an Arthurian plot

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was published in *Asimov's* or *Analog* within the last 10 years.

Unusual story of two robot like creatures named Rok and Mog who lived on a dark, metallic planet, lots of clinks, clanks, and spires.  Had a sort of Arthurian plot where one of them scales a spire to save a female type robot/machine? I pictured them as metal spider creatures.  There was also a humanoid creature who got paid and wanted to buy 'a sex from a Johnny' or something like that.

I believe this is the same author who wrote a more recent story about economics and space/time travel, with immortal space ships with names like *Dividends* and *Profit*, that captured the protagonist and time traveled him to avoid an encroaching black hole that was eating the universe.  It time looped around with DNA clones of customers or shareholders to repopulate the universe.

Answer (score 2):

This has to be "[The Way of the Needle](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1413399)" (2012) by Derek Künsken, published in *Asimov's*, March 2012, though it misses on a few points.  You can read it at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v36n03_2012-03/page/n15/mode/2up).

The world is indeed dark, "illuminated" by the spinning magnetic field of the pulsar it orbits:

> The ancient pulsar's lighthouse beam of microwaves and radio waves spun twice per second. Within the bloom of its magnetic field orbited the single planet that had survived the long-ago supernova, at the cost of its crust and mantle. An atmosphere of carbon dioxide had congealed around the little metallic world, producing oceans of iron and nickel carbonyl, dotted with thickets of steel needles that fanned to catch the microwaves.

There are indeed lots of spikes ("needles," "quills," "spines"), which is how the eight-legged inhabitants harvest the magnetic field:

> On the largest islands, the growth of the needles had been coaxed into towers, pedestals, and martial walls. Prickly metal creatures held together by strong magnetic fields scuttled in these towns and forts, on eight articulated legs of steel spines. Their fine quills caught the flashing microwaves, generating the electricity for their quick, agile movements.

The protagonist's name is **Mok**, a member of a monastic order, who has shed its fighting claws to go under cover as a "swarmer" (essentially a serf) in order to kill a rogue former master of the order:

> Mok was a Follower of the Needle, an order of martial priests. Whereas other Followers and fighters-at-arms bore large metal claws high on their forelegs, Mok now scurried with only small, shameful servant claws. No one recognized him and no one complimented him. Nor would he earn any compliments from this mission; he'd been sent by Master Hac not as a warrior to fight under the full shine of the pulsar, but as an assassin.

Mok meets, and is helped by **Rag**, a struggling member of the servant caste (a "swarmer"):

> At the entrance to the Ban manor house, someone took Mok gently by his upper spines, and helped him to his feet. Mok found a decrepit swarmer facing him. Mok stood uncertainly. Normally, when a swarmer helped him, they gave him a tip. What did they do amongst themselves?
>
> "He got you with all of that, didn't he?" the swarmer said with the diction of a rod chopper. "He bent a few."
>
> Mok tested his shoulders. They were whole. He felt at the bends in his upper spines. Then, reluctantly, he scraped a gratuity off a lower spine. The swarmer looked at him strangely, but took the food.
>
> "I'm Rag."
>
> "Mok."

Rag helps Mok a few more times, ultimately nearly sacrificing itself to assist Mok in successfully completing its mission.  In return Mok saves and restores Rag and gives Rag an honoured position in Mok's entourage.

It may be that you're conflating a few stories, however, because this doesn't really have an Arthurian feel to it, and there's no sex.  (The beings living in this world reproduce by budding, as shown in the story "[Tidal Maneuvers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?953558)," whose hero Pik needs to save itself and its bud.)

Künsken does have a story an AI (Ulixes-316) is trying to outrace a disaster that is destroying the universe ("[Flight from the Ages](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1999290)," *Asimov's*, April-May 2016), with ships named *The Derivatives Market* and *The Bull Market*, so that matches too.  (Ulixes is carrying the encoded AIs of the shareholders though, not their DNA.)